# The number of users - curious jumps

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I check how many users of `mathematica.stackexchange.com` there are.
I remember that a few weeks ago there were about 15 thousand and recently I've been surprised seeing that  the [new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) are signed with numbers over 18000.
Let's check [this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?page=21&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate), the new users therein have numbers slightly over 14000.  The registry number of new users included `21` pages with `4 X 9 = 36`  new users which is less than `800 << 18000 - 15000`.

What is going on?

Let's look  at  [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?page=18&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate), the number of  [user49115](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14837/user49115) is `14837` while the next one in the registry is [Jazz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/15838/jazz) having the number `15838` i.e `15838 = 14837 + 1001`.

I know I can find e.g. how many [teachers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1/teacher) or [students](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/2/student) there are, but the number of all users is also interesting.

So what is the reliable number of all users (including unregistered) and of those who are regeistered?

Comment: Some of them are bots that get destroyed quickly by spam filters, which might explain the difference.

Comment: bots, crocks and frogs

Comment: @belisarius you mean fraugs

Comment: @rm-rf, it seems there was a different reason. I wonder now if what you are saying is correct, that SE can destroy accounts from bots in the site.

Comment: @caya I don't know what exactly SE does behind the scenes, but I certainly can destroy accounts and have done so. That still won't explain a contiguous block of 1000 users missing, so Oded's answer is the only explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to how our databases are setup and operate.

The Id field (user number) is an auto incrementing field - essentially when a user gets created, it takes the next number (not entirely accurate, there are some wrinkles there, not relevant to this).

We operate with replication - our databases are replicated between data centers to help with backup and for disaster recovery (if a datacenter/database goes down, we have a replica with near to current data).

In our [always-on configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff877884.aspx), to avoid too much network chatter between replicas, seeds are pre-allocated in chunks of 1000 (standard behavior for SQL Server 2012 and above, if I understand things correctly).

If there is a replication hiccup, the result is pretty much what you see.

We did upgrade our database servers around the time of this gap - so, it all fits nicely together...

Comment: Thanks for explaning the problem. So if I uderstand correctly the registry numbers of  new users are not reliable measures of the total number of users?

Comment: @Artes - they never were. The way identity fields work, they will increment also on a failed attempt - so if current max Id is 111, a failed attempt to create a new user will increment the underlying sequence to 112, a successful creation will increment again, to 113, leaving a hole. This is normal for database operations and is one reason to never use these Ids as meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

Now that the technical side of this has been answered I'll attempt to address:

> So what is the reliable number of all users (including unregistered) and of those who are registered?

The [Stack Exchange User Reputation Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/177/alltime/mathematica) page provides some apparently useful data:

> Q&A for users of Mathematica (12,957 total users)

It also gives a break-down by reputation which provides a useful way to measure participating members:

```
Total Reputation
Total Rep*  Users
100,000+    1
50,000+     5
25,000+     17
10,000+     44
5,000+      69
3,000+      95
2,000+      137
1,000+      214
500+        362
200+        728
1+          11,285
```

Why this page says that we have 1,672 more members than those with 1 reputation point I don't know.

From this data I estimate that we have about one thousand members with a reputation of 100 points, indicating either significant participation or activity on other Stack Exchange sites.

On a personal note I am pleased to see that we have 44 major hitters (10k+) now.

(Update by belisarius follows. User Rep. Leagues as of Feb 10, 2015)

```
Total Rep*  Users
100,000+    1
50,000+     7
25,000+     20
10,000+     51
5,000+      80
3,000+      116
2,000+      171
1,000+      254
500+        443
200+        898
1+          14,641
```

Comment: Looking at the users tab there are about 5000 users with 100 rep or more (of which about 3300 have 101)

Comment: The discrepancy might be because unregistered users are not counted in certain places.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.