# Why the first user here has number 4, not 1?

Tags: support

Just out of curiosity.

- [A search for User#1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1) returns nothing.
- [A search for User#2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2) returns nothing.
- [A search for User#3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3) returns nothing.
- Finally [a search for User#4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4) shows FDSg.

Searches for users up to #10 do return results, [except one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6).

Why is that so? WHY THE GAPS?

I suspect one of the following:

- the first users are SE employees and admins, so they have no posts (as they are just running the site) and thus are noth found by the search engine; am I right?
- the first users had their accounts deleted. Less likely, as AFAIK people insist on deleting their accounts only in rare situations, and I can't see how could the very first users be vandals/spammers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Some user accounts have been either merged or deleted
- See also [The number of users - curious jumps](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1347/121)

Other than that use the URL template `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/#` where `#` is the user number, if looking for users by number.

You will find:

- [Geoff Dalgas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1/geoff-dalgas)
- [Nick Craver](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2/nick-craver)
- [Rebecca Chernoff](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3/rebecca-chernoff)

The first three accounts were created for Stack Exchange employees to administer the site, especially during the beta phase.  You were correct.